# Drawing radar charts using Highcharts in Angular2

Tags: angular, highcharts

I am using [angular2-highcharts](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-highcharts) and I have set it up successfully.

If I use the following code

```
constructor(private emotionsService: EmotionsService) {
        this.options = {
            title: { text : 'dynamic data example'},
            series: [{
                data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2],
            }]
        };
    }
    options: HighchartsOptions;
```

It works perfectly well.
However, I want to draw a radar chart/[Spider Web](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/polar-spider). I added the following line inside the options.

```
 xAxis: {
                categories: ['Sales', 'Marketing', 'Development', 'Customer Support',
                    'Information Technology', 'Administration'],
            },

            yAxis: {
                gridLineInterpolation: 'polygon',
            },
```

It complains about the property incompatible as below:

```
chart: { polar: boolean; }; xAxis: { categories: string[]; }; yAxis: { gridLineInterpolation: s...' is not assignable to type 'HighchartsOptions'.
[0]   Types of property 'yAxis' are incompatible.
```

Is it possible to draw Spider chart with this npm module.

Answer (score 0):

The Spider requires to use the highcharts-more.js file. You need to add the reference to the file in the `systemjs.config.js`

```
  var  map = {
    'app':                        'app', // 'dist',
    'rxjs':                       'https://npmcdn.com/rxjs@5.0.0-beta.6',
    'angular2-in-memory-web-api': 'https://npmcdn.com/angular2-in-memory-web-api', // get latest,
    'angular2-highcharts':        'https://cdn.rawgit.com/gevgeny/angular2-highcharts/0.1.0/dist', 
    'highcharts/highstock.src':   'https://cdn.rawgit.com/highcharts/highcharts-dist/v4.2.1/highstock.js',
    'highcharts/highcharts-more':   'https://cdn.rawgit.com/highcharts/highcharts-dist/v4.2.1/highcharts-more.src.js',
  };
```

and then set reference by Import in the application.

```
import { bootstrap }                    from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { Component }                    from '@angular/core';
import { CHART_DIRECTIVES, Highcharts } from 'angular2-highcharts'; 
import HighchartsMore                     from 'highcharts/highcharts-more';   

HighchartsMore(Highcharts);
```

Last step is set "polar" in chart object.

```
constructor() {
    this.options = {
      chart: {
        type: 'column',
        polar: true
      },
      series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
      }]
    };
}
```

Fixed demo:

- http://plnkr.co/edit/HCbX8kxvhCDxww3HWiG5?p=preview

Comment: I added `require('highcharts/highcharts-more.js')(Highcharts);` in the module.ts file.

Comment: It works well with that. Thanks for the answer. If you could just modify that in your answer, I wiil accept it.